# I need 2 different buttons, to create new folder and create a new PDF in that folder

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

I've been struggling to build a specific weekly stock system reports. So to give you a basic overview, I have a mastersheet that I want to generate reports from, triggered by an UI button. The first step however is to create a folder for that week to place the PDF's in. I can create the folder, and I can generate the PDF in my root Google Drive folder, but I can't seem to move the PDF anywhere after that. I have attempted to use .moveTo() but I can't get that to work. Does anyone have any advise?

```
function onOpen(e) 
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Physical')
      .addItem('New folder','newFolder')
      .addItem('Generate PDF','generatePDF')
      .addToUi();
}

function newFolder(){
 var today = new Date();
  var week = Utilities.formatDate(today, "Europe/Amsterdam", "w"); //need to find a way to minus 1 for the current week

var spreadsheetId =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); //time to create a new folder
    var spreadsheetFile =  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
    var folderId = spreadsheetFile.getParents().next().getId();
    var parFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
    var destFolder = parFolder.createFolder('Week ' + week);
}

function generatePDF(){
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var speadsheetFile = ss.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(speadsheetFile);
  var folderId = file.getParents().next().getId();
  var pdf = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob())
  pdf.moveTo(folderId); //find way to move file either to destination folder or to parent folder
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

These types of situations are hard to test because the circumstances are specific to the OP questioner.  However, I believe this will work.

Using the PropertyService Script Properties, store the newly created folderId and then get that id from Script Properties to move the file.

A note of caution, I didn't check for the case if the week changes and a new folder is not created, the pdf will go to the previous week folder.

Regarding creating a button and linking a function to the button see this article [Buttons in Google Sheets](https://spreadsheet.dev/buttons-in-google-sheets)

**Script**

```
function newFolder(){
  var today = new Date();
  var week = Utilities.formatDate(today, "Europe/Amsterdam", "w"); //need to find a way to minus 1 for the current week

  var spreadsheetId =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); //time to create a new folder
  var spreadsheetFile =  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
  var folderId = spreadsheetFile.getParents().next().getId();
  var parFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var folderName = 'Week '+week;
  // check if folder already exists
  var subFolders = parFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  var destFolder = null;
  if( subFolders.hasNext() ) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Folder "+folderName+" already exists");
    destFolder = subFolders.next();
  }
  else {
    destFolder = parFolder.createFolder(folderName);
  }
  // store folder id to Script Properties
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  props.setProperty("foldeId",destFolder.getId());
}

function generatePDF(){
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // get folder id from Script Properties
  var folderId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties("folderId");
  if( !folderId ) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Property folderId not found");
    return;
  }
  var pdf = DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob())
  pdf.moveTo(folderId); //find way to move file either to destination folder or to parent folder
}
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#alert(String))
- [PropetiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service?hl=en#getScriptProperties())

Comment: Hey man, this did end up working, sort of, I had to tweak it a bit, but never knew about ScriptProperties, so thanks so much for that one! Appreciate the help.